# Algebraic closure of limit existence?

Tags: calculus, limits

**Problem:** If $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)+g(x)]=2$ and $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)-g(x)]=1$, then find $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)g(x)]$.

I came up with a way that I know works, but someone else showed me a more interesting way of going about it...

We know
$$
\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)+g(x)]^2=(\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)+g(x)])^2=4=\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)^2+2f(x)g(x)+g(x)^2)\tag{1}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)-g(x)]^2=(\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)-g(x)])^2=1=\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)^2-2f(x)g(x)+g(x)^2).\tag{2}
$$
By subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$, we get
$$
\lim_{x\to a}4[f(x)g(x)]=3
$$
or 
$$
\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)g(x)]=\frac{3}{4}.
$$
Even though the *result* of $3/4$ is correct, is this not a logical violation? Were the limit laws used properly? It doesn't seem as though we should be able to subtract $(2)$ from $(1)$ in the way it was. Even if this were valid (is it?), then would it be correct to say $\lim_{x\to a}4[f(x)g(x)]=3$ is the same as $4\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)g(x)]$? Wouldn't this be using another limit law that *assumed* the existence of $\lim_{x\to a}[f(x)g(x)]$?

Comment: Subtracting the two limits is valid, since if $\lim a,\lim b$ exist, then so does $\lim(a-b)$ and is equal to $\lim a-\lim b$. As for the second one, you can use the the fact that if limit of something exists, then the limit of $1/4$ times this something also exists. You should get used to the fact that most mathematicians leave out such details from limit computations, assuming the reader can fill in all the details if interested.

Comment: Ah, I see your concern.  It's acceptable as:  let h (x)=4f (x)g (x).  We know $\lim h(x)=3$ so we know $\lim \frac 14 h (x)=3/4$.  And $\frac 14 h (x) =f (x)g (x) $

Answer (score 1):

It's very good that you should be dubious and careful!

But we have a theorem that if

$\lim f (x)= k $ and $\lim g (x)=j $ then $\lim cf (x)=ck $ and $\lim[ f (x)+g (x)]=k+j $ and $\lim f (x)g (x)=kj $ and if $k\ne 0$ then $\lim \frac 1 {f (x)}=\frac 1k $.

So *everything* there is perfectly valid!

....

Which isn't to say that in $\lim f (x)g (x)= k $ that $\lim f (x) $ or $\lim g (x)$ actually exist.

... oh, I see your concern!

We know $\lim h(x)=k\implies \lim ch (x)=ck $ but that wouldn't mean $\lim ch (x)=k\implies \lim h (x)=\frac kc $ if we don't know the limit exists in the first place.

But it does!

Let $j (x)=ch (x) $ then we have $\lim j (x) =\lim ch (x)=k $.  So $\lim \frac 1c j (x) =\frac 1c k $.

===

Redo:

Everything is valid.

Let $j (x)=f (x)+g (x) $ let $k (x)=f (x)-g (x) $.  Let $h (x)=4f (x)g (x)=j^2 (x)-k^2 (x) $.

$\lim j (x)=2$; $\lim k (x)=1$ so $\lim h (x)=\lim( j^2 (x)-k^2 (x))=2^2-1^2=3$

So $\lim \frac 14 h (x)=\lim f (x)g (x)=\frac 14 *3=\frac 34$.

This is perfectly legitimate even if $\lim f (x) $ or $\lim g (x)$ don't exist.

Comment: Maybe you should attempt to prove that theorem rather than taking my word for it.  They are simple delta epsilon proves but the multiples and quotient  get a little tricky.

Comment: One place where the theorem alluded to is proved is Baby Rudin 3.3.  The very first thing I'd do in the problem is verify, using that theorem, that $\lim_{x\to a} f$ and $\lim_{x\to a} g$ exist.  I'd then give them names, $F$ and $G$ for example, and solve the equations $F+G=2$, $F-G=1$.  Thus I do not like your (the OP's) "more interesting" way.

Comment: lim f and lim g don't need to exist!.  let h (x) = 4f (x)g (x).  The limit of h (x) can exist as h (x) =j^2 (x)-k ^2 (x) where j =f+g and k=f-g and those limits exist.

Comment: Umm, if $\lim (f+g)$ exists, and $\lim (f-g)$ exists, then $\lim f={1\over2}(\lim (f+g)+\lim (f-g))$ and $\lim g={1\over2}(\lim (f+g)-\lim (f-g))$ also exist.  Perhaps Baby Rudin 4.4 is a better cite.  Stewart's *Calculus* section 2.3 also works.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

use

$$ab=\frac {(a+b)^2-(a-b)^2}{4} $$

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight generalization of the algebra of limits which is used implicitly almost everywhere, but not mentioned explicitly in most textbooks:

We have $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \pm g(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x) \pm \lim_{x\to a} g(x) $$ provided at least **one** of the limits on right exists and $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) g(x) =\lim_{x\to a} f(x) \cdot \lim_{x\to a} g(x) $$ provided at least **one of the limits on right exists and is nonzero**.

The above rules allow us to apply algebra of limits without worrying too much about existence of limits of sub-expressions while evaluating limit of a complicated expression. The questions of existence of limits get settled during the process of evaluation itself.

Your example is simpler and it does not really require the above generalization, the usual rules of limits mentioned in textbooks suffice. Each step in your calculation is validated by a specific rule and your concern about the validity of such steps is more than what is usually necessary. Thus we use the product rule when we square the limits, then the rule for subtraction of limits is used and finally the quotient rule is used (although here the quotient is by a constant function $4$).